# Try Catch - Resource intensity?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've read that using Try Catch blocks in SQL Server stored procedures can chow a lot of server resources. My question is just how much resources does it use?

I currently make use of Try Catch blocks and Transactions whenever my sproc is making a lot of data changes, which is great for preventing incorrect data from entering the db and also for logging the errors, but I'd like to make use of this method of programming in all my sprocs.

How much of a difference does it make?

Comment: Where did you read that? Have you a link?

Comment: I've done a bit of testing on this - see http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/error-handling

Comment: I've read that in a book back when I was in university, can't remember the exact name though.
It does make sense that it will take some resources to check for errors, but I'm just wondering how much.

Comment: @JAT - Was that talking about SQL Server specifically or `try ... catch` generally?

Comment: @MartinSmith I assume they were talking about SQL Server specifically, since it was a SQL handbook, but I can't say for sure. Authors these days will print just about any statistic. 
It does make sense that it will take some resources to check for errors, but I'm just wondering how much.

Comment: @JAT - I would guess that when an error occurs the error handling routine just branches to the catch block rather than needing to do any additional checks for errors.

Comment: @MartinSmith So in your experience, you have not noticed a significant difference between using and not using Try Catch blocks?

Comment: @JAT - No there definitely is no significant difference from simply having the statements in a `BEGIN TRY ... END TRY BEGIN CATCH ... END CATCH`. I've never tested whether there is any measurable difference but if it exists it will be small.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Zero. Code using TRY/CATCH consumes exactly the same resources as code not using TRY/CATCH, only difference is that the former is usually more correct than the later. In fact TRY/CATCH code is *more* efficient in presence of errors as the code flow jumps straight to the catch block and avoids running the rest of the statements in the request/stored procedure only to roll back at the end.

Just for the record, I don't buy for a single second that writing code that checks for @@ERROR after each statement is even *remotely* a viable alternative.

> I've read that in a book back when I was in university

For sure the reading did not refer to T-SQL code with TRY/CATCH, but instead was referring C++ code with or without exception (of JVM, or IL). Back in the dark ages there was a dispute about whether adding the exception handling code has performance impact (yes, it has) and whether we should consider this a factor (no, we shouldn't, code with exception handling has long since won that battle due to *correctness*). But this discussion is completely useless for your point of view: the back end engine that runs your T-SQL is compiled with exception handling and there is nothing you can do about it. Again, this has 0 impact on your T-SQL code.

Comment: Thank you. I love using Try Catch in my scripts, but have always been told not to use it due to the high volume of transactions we handle. My logic also told me that it would be more efficient to end a script immediately after an error occurred, rather than having to query the @@ERROR first. 
Thanks

Comment: Somehow related: http://rusanu.com/2009/06/11/exception-handling-and-nested-transactions/